# jQuery: triggering close of mobile nav menu

Tags: jquery, navigationbar

I have an extremely basic jQuery click function that toggles the display of a mobile nav menu-- hamburger-style, triggered by media query-- that is as follows:

```
// mobile menu click function
$(".mobile-nav-toggle").click(function () {
    $(".mobile-nav-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Thus, clicking the `.mobile-nav-toggle` div triggers the appearance of `.mobile-nav-menu` which is positioned under a main header bar. My question is-- is there a simple way via jQuery to trigger closing/hiding the menu by clicking/tapping anywhere *outside* the menu itself? As it stands, one can only close the menu by re-clicking/tapping the toggle button.

Thanks for any insight here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a click handler added to the document itself like

```js
// mobile menu click function
$(".mobile-nav-toggle").click(function() {
  $(".mobile-nav-menu").slideToggle();
});
$(document).click(function(e) {
  //if the click has happend inside the mobile-nav-menu or mobile-nav-toggle then ignore it
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.mobile-nav-menu, .mobile-nav-toggle').length) {
    $(".mobile-nav-menu").slideUp();
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.mobile-nav-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mobile-nav-toggle">Toggle</button>
<div class="mobile-nav-menu">menu
  <div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, that works perfectly! One more related question-- how might I also have the menu close when a user clicks a link within the menu? I have the links displayed in an unordered list within the `.mobile-nav-menu` div. Thanks again!

Comment: @nickpish do you want the menu to close if the user click anywehre within the `mobile-nav-menu` element, if so try `if (!$(e.target).closest('.mobile-nav-toggle').length) {`

Comment: yes-- I'm thinking if the user actually clicks a link within the mobile nav bar, that would also trigger the menu to close while the linked page starts to load...

Comment: While this works perfectly on the desktop, I'm noticing that this click handler doesn't seem to work with touch/tap on an iPad; do you have any idea why this might be or if there's a library that can assist with this kind of issue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code

```
$(".mobile-nav-toggle").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".mobile-nav-menu").slideToggle();
});

$(document).click( function(){
    $('.mobile-nav-menu').hide();
});
```