# hide responsive menu in mobile mode using jQuery click

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, responsive

Please help with my jQuery logic. I need one more `$().click` statement to close the entire menu in mobile device mode and toggle the hamburger button to before state. All my attempts thus far either hide the menu in desktop mode as well or mess with the sub-menu clicks.

I built this by studying a number of tutorials and combined the best of them all, only this final click got me stumped. Almost all responsive menus rely on the menu being reset when loaded into a new page and does not provide for it closing when navigating to anchor links or menu loaded in an iframe.

Closest answer I got is this one but it does not allow for sub-menus:
[jQuery: triggering close of mobile nav menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904886/jquery-triggering-close-of-mobile-nav-menu)

```js
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready
    // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      // Close one dropdown when selecting another
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    // Hamburger to X toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); // end DOM ready
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #2581DC;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="#!">OASA</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile">
        <a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Services</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Web Development</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what the problem is. When I use your code, the whole thing seems to work fine. I am able to see the expanded desktop menu, then when I shrink my screen, I can see the mobile menu button appear. Both menus seem to work fine and i can close the mobile menu without any trouble. Are you trying to keep your menu on a static page and then load the selected page in an iframe? Can you expand just a bit more on what the issue actually is?

Comment: Currently I can only hide the mobile menu when I click the menu button. I want it to hide when I click on any menu item or anywhere outside the menu as well. What I cannot figure out is how to hide the main menu in mobile mode but not desktop mode without breaking the sub-menu function. The sub-menu items hide perfect when I click them or any other item now I need to do the same with the main menu as well.